# Find the $\mathcal Z$-transform of this function?

Tags: signal-analysis, z-transform

I need to find the $\mathcal Z$-transform of $x(n)=a^{-n} u(n)$. Assume, $a$ is a positive constant , but the power of $a$ is negative.

Looking at the transform table, I found that $\mathcal Z$-transform for $x(n)=a^{-n} u(n)$ is not there, so I tried to found it by on my own, but I am not sure if my answer is right, please can anyone check it and correct me, in case?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Doing some calculations is appreciated. However, it is preferred that you write them in the question because a picture can vanish more easily. Do not hesitate to edit the math.

To help you with an hint in checking your answer, remember that:

$$ a^{-n} = \left(\frac{1}{a}\right)^n$$

a standard trick to play with known tables.

Answer (score 1):

The $X(z)$ calculated is correct but there are some mistakes in the steps and ROC is wrong.

1. $X[z]$ is wrong representation of $\mathcal Z$-Transform since it is not a discrete sequence but rather a continuous function of $z$, where $z$ is a complex variable in argand plane ($z$-plane).
2. Limit of $\sum$ changes from $n=0$ to $\infty$ to $n=1$ to $\infty$. Why? That's not right.
3. $a^{-n}$ and $z^{-n}$ changes to $a^{n}$ and $z^{n}$ inside $\sum$. Not correct.
4. The ROC is the region on $z$-plane where the $\mathcal Z$ transform summation becomes finite in absolute sense. For any Causal Sequence like yours ($a^{-n}u[n]$), the ROC is complete region extending to $\infty$ from the largest pole of $\mathcal Z$-transform which is $\frac{1}{a}$ in your case. Basically, ROC will be $|az| > 1$ . This is easy to see from the $\mathcal Z$-Transform expression itself:

$X(z) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (az)^{-n}$

Answer (score 1):

Consider a Discrete time signal and analyze its transformation into DTFT,
Z-transform.
With examples represent various ROC for any signal or sequence

Answer (score -2):

No you have done a small mistake how a^-n became a^n? So it is like this the ROC is right sided[image: the procedure is like this]

Comment: Please, use the formatting options provided by the site to write your answer instead of posting images.

Comment: I don't know how to do such things

Comment: You can check out how to improve your formatting [here](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/editing-help).

Comment: Moni alfarsia if you put your question as answered then it is better

Comment: Ok , Iam sorry but Its my first time that I have post in this website , In second time make sure that I will not post a picture .

Comment: ok , I am so shamed really . sorry